# java- how to handle error logging in a multi threaded web app

Tags: java, multithreading

In a web app, I am parsing multiple XML files simultaneously using multi threading.

Now, at different stages of the parsing process messages are being sent to the log.

I am trying to put correct message into log when an error occurs- but how do I ensure that if one thread fails for some reason, then the entire list of messages for that specific error is sent to log in one single block? i.e. different threads' messages should not be mixed up (as this will make it very difficult for me to understand exactly what the error was and which thread reported the error).

Answer (score 1):

You should leverage [Log4j's MDC or NDC.](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC)

Answer (score 1):

In this cases, you should use MDC or NDC see for example http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/

So every thread will have a unique id and the error messages will be written again this unique id.

When searching for any error in the log file for a particular thread, you can grep the lines by this Id.

I dont think trying to maintain a sequence of lines per thread for logging is a good idea from design and performance perspective.

See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
myLogContainer=CreateLogContainer();
myLogContainer.push(logMessage);
myLogContainer.push(logMessage);
myLogContainer.push(logMessage);
..
myLogContainer.push(logMessage);
logger.submit(myLogContainer);
myLogContainer=CreateLogContainer(); // ready for next lot of errors
```

Comment: Not a reinvention - it's pseudocode for what could happen.  Building such a design within, or on top of, a logging framework that is already proven is just fine!